# In a convective system involving a solid and a fluid, does the convective heat transfer coefficient depend on the thermal conductivity of the solid?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, convection

If so, why? And what are the other factors that affect the value of heat transfer coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the temperature of the solid at the surface does not change, the solid does not affect the convective heat transfer coefficient on the fluid side of the boundary.  The heat transfer coefficient depends on the details of the fluid flow, whether the flow is turbulent or not, the viscosity, heat capacity, and density of the fluid, the characteristic dimension(s) of the geometry (if any), and, if the temperature difference across the boundary layer is large, the values of the physical properties at the surface and in the free stream.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Can you pl also elaborate on what exactly you mean by h on the "fluid" side, since I always assumed heat transfer coefficient was defined for a particular process, not the solid/fluid in question?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but by "fluid side" I mean the fluid side of the interface.